# Handling upload errors

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm using fine-uploader with AngularJS. This is the configuration I am using in my HTML file:

```
<div fine-uploader
     upload-server="{{ uploadServer }}"
     not-available-placeholder="/vendor/jquery.fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png"
     waiting-placeholder="/vendor/jquery.fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png"
     max-file-size="10000000"
     large-preview-size="500"
     allowed-mimes="image/jpeg, image/png"
     allowed-extensions="jpeg, jpg, png"
     token="{{ token }}">
</div>
```

How do I:

1. Handle file upload errors? For example, I would like to display a custom AngularJS dialog when an upload error happens. Is there any sample code that illustrates how to do this? I already have my own dialog code I can call.
2. Limit the number of retries to 1?

Comment: The simple answer here is "use whatever dialog you are already using to display an upload error message". You haven't demonstrated why this isn't possible. Also, to limit the number of retries, make use of the [retry.maxAutoAttempts option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#retry.maxAutoAttempts).

Comment: Thanks for the help.To limit the retries would the HTML tag be "max-auto-attempts"? Is there an example of how to handle an upload error event in Angular? I can't demonstrate why this isn't possible because I don't know how to handle an upload error in the first place. That is the problem.

Comment: You'll need to modify your directive appropriately. Ultimately, it will need to rely on whatever mechanism you are using to detect errors, such as the [`onError` callback](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/handling-errors.html).

Comment: I modifed my directive with a handler for the onError callback as you suggested. The handler does get triggered correctly. Is there a way to get the actual response of a bad upload request instead of a generic status code. For example, I see an errorReason set to the value "XHR returned response code 400". Can I get the actual full response? In my situation the response contains more meaningful detail than a 400 status code.

Comment: Please see [the events documentation page](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html). And then choose the most appropriate event for your situation.